# Configuring Kafka JDBC Sink to INSERT JSON formatted columns as string

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to sink a dataset to an sql store using JDBC sink connector.. A couple of the columns are formatted in json but I would like to insert them as string. My schema registry seems to be working fine and the problematic columns in the registry ("ISPINFO" and "EXTRA" fields) are listed as "string" in the registry. Following is what I see in the sink logs when the data is processed:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "test" ("ID","TIMESTAMP","IP","ISPINFO","EXTRA","UA","LANG","DL","UL","PING","JITTER","LOG") VALUES (29,1619794623771,'23.23.23.23','{"processedString":"23.23.23.23 - Data Centers Inc., CA (3500 km)","rawIspInfo":{"ip":"23.23.23.23","city":"sdfdsf","region":"sdfdf","country":"CA","loc":"34.5088,-27.5878","org":"AS10929","postal":"H2R","timezone":"America/Toronto","readme":"https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"}}'::json,'{"server":"test-mashine"}'::json,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36','en-US,en;q=0.9',31.18,8.55,93.89,53.84,'') was aborted: ERROR: Cannot find data type: json  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Cannot find data type: json
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Cannot find data type: json
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.getAllMessagesException(JdbcSinkTask.java:150)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:102)
        ... 11 more 
11:04
```

I tried the following in my properties file:

```
transforms=Cast
transforms.Cast.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Value
transforms.Cast.spec="ISPINFO":string,"EXTRA":string
```

But that didnt help. I am still seeing the same error in the log. Is there anyway to insert those two columns as string? My database can insert these records if those those columns are inserted without the "::json" next to the value.

Following is my schema taken from the _schema topic:

```
{"subject":"VALIDATOR_AVRO-value","version":2,"id":12,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"KsqlDataSourceSchema\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"ID\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"TIMESTAMP\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"long\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"IP\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"ISPINFO\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"EXTRA\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"UA\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"LANG\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"DL\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"double\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"UL\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"double\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"PING\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"double\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"JITTER\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"double\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"LOG\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null}]}","deleted":false}
```

Basically, my setup is as follow: everything is built on the same system. Things are produced in json to kafka, then I use ksql to convert it to avro and register it to a local schema registry. from there I use the jdbc sink to insert the record to a local relational database.

Thank you.

Comment: The issue seems to be the `::json` part of the query. I don't think casting is what you want if the fields are already string type

Comment: Yep, that is my issue. Is there a way to remove that and insert the problematic columns just like a string input?

Comment: So, you're using the AvroConverter? Can you show the schema?

Comment: I just updated my original message with my schema.

Comment: Thanks. Not really clear to me why the connector thinks those fields should be JSON, though... For example, the UA is a string field and it doesn't have `::json` on the query. A plain string is also valid JSON, doesn't need `{}`